# How can I detect if a photo has already been imported to a photo album?

Tags: ios, photo

I've got an app that copies screenshots from another device onto an iOS device and adds them to a photo album, using `[ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL]` and `[ALAssetsGroup addAsset]`. But every time I do this it adds the screenshots even if they've been added previously. Is there a way of knowing whether I've previously imported an image? I can't use the filename because the screenshots use a simple index that gets incremented.